# i want to make oncontextmenu Event on right click

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, gridview

> I want to make my own menu comes up when right click on my mouse?
>   I want to do it by ajax or java script or JQuery my page is in asp.net.

My grid design -

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
      <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField  DataField="Id" HeaderText="ID" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Patient Name" />
     </Columns>

</asp:GridView>
```

i just want to know how can i design a menu in that click i got a right click event on my page now i just want the way of making menu

Answer (score 0):

The right click on mouse can be detected with any of `mousedown`, `mouseup`, etc.

The best methode is to use `oncontextmenu`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(this).bind("contextmenu", function (e) {
             // Right click is pressed
             // add your ajax here
            $.ajax({
                 type: 'POST',
                 url: 'PATH TO URL',
                 success: function(){
                      // code
                 }
            })
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: and how to make context menu ? can u tell me brother?

Comment: path to url? means path of context menu?

Comment: u require jquery to run above script, and op did not mention that he need jquery solution

Answer (score 0):

You can put your grid inside div element and use contextmenu attribute like this-

```
<div oncontextmenu="javascript:alert('success!');return false;">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="White" BorderStyle="Ridge" BorderWidth="2px" CellPadding="3" GridLines="None" Height="90px" Width="452px" CellSpacing="1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged1">
    ..............
    ..............
    ..............
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

However, users generally expect the right-click to bring up the default context menu provided by the browser. iOS devices don't even have right click. So, designing your custom context menu in the web environment is not-so-good idea actually.

Comment: can u share some more details about it ?